# What is the difference between a sudo and a root user?

Tags: command-line, sudo

I'm using the windows subsystem for linux, I'm very new to ubuntu and I can't get my head around the root user concept.

Answer (score 2):

**root** - is a user (with no restrictions)

**sudo** - just command which give you rights to run another command with root user privileges. **sudo** must be run every time before the command, which you want to execute as root user.